# get current user in service layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to get current user in service layer

I tried the following code but get null pointer exception

```
@Service
public class MyService{

@Autowired
TodoRepository todoRepository;

public void execute(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setDomain(auth.getName());
    todoRepository.save(todo);  
}
```

Can anyone show me how can i get login user by spring security in service layer ?

Comment: Where do you get the null pointer exception? In theory it should never be null if it is you have a problem in your setup.

Comment: Do you always call the service layer from the web layer? SecurityContext works based on thread scope (request). If you launch some async methods this fails as it will be another thread.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you find the currently authenticated user :

```
 @Override
    public Person getCurrentlyAuthenticatedUser() {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                            .getAuthentication();

        if (authentication == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            // The line below calls the method from my Person database, 
            // where I search users by their Email(username)
            return personDAO.findPersonByUsername(authentication.getName());
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps. If not, please let me kno,w I will delete my answer.

Comment: This not work because  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() get null

Comment: Means currently there is no logged in user or your Spring-security setup is incorrect. I am using that method in production for more then 6 months.

Comment: This works fine in controller layer but get null exception in service layer

Comment: Paste your service layer entirely with imports and annotations. No need to paste contents of method. Also paste the error log and at which line you get the error. Please edit your main post to do so. if you have something ApplicationContext.xml and securityAppplication.xml, paste those too. It is not possible to guess blindly what might be the problem.